# Combine two object keys in and array without loosing the value

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I have an object that I'm mapping through its keys in my react component to display header titles.

```
obj1 = {
  TERM_NOTE: 'TERM_NOTE',
  EQUITY: 'EQUITY',
  REVENUE_SHARING_NOTE: 'REVENUE_SHARING_NOTE',
  CONVERTIBLE_NOTES: 'CONVERTIBLE_NOTES',
  SAFE: 'SAFE',
  FUNDS: 'FUNDS',
}
const keytermsSecurityTypes = Object.keys(obj1);

keytermsSecurityTypes.forEach((type) => {
      listAsPerSecurityType[type] = props.investments.filter(i => get(i, 'offering.keyTerms.securities') === type);
      listHeaderAsPerSecurityType[type] = listMetaByType.filter(i => i.securityType.includes('ALL') || i.securityType.includes(type));
    });
```

and the variables mentioned before are used inside the React component:

```
keytermsSecurityTypes.map(type => (
 <>
   {listAsPerSecurityType[type] && listAsPerSecurityType[type].length
   && (
      <>
        <Header as="h5" className="investment-list" content={getSecurityHeaderTitle(type)} />
        <ListTable listData={listAsPerSecurityType[type]} header={listHeaderAsPerSecurityType[type]}/>
      </>
      )}
 </>
))
```

for CONVERTIBLE_NOTES and SAFE keys, title should display as "Convertible Securities" for both as one title. However I still need to keep the values of both keys as they are being used in the same component as well.

While I got the title to display the same string for both keys, I still can't figure out how to combine them into one title.

Also, considering I'm still new to React and javascript, is there a better way/best practice to do this?

Desired output:
[Design spec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTpUR.png)

Problem output:
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac9kx.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post a sample of `props.investments`? And the `keytermsSecurityTypes` that you're iterating over?

Comment: props.investments is an array of objects:
`
[
  {
  city: "string",
  discout: "string",
  keyTerms: {
    securities: "SAFE",
    someOtherKey: "string" 
  }
  },
  {}, {}]
`
and keyTermsSecurityTypes is the keys array of the obj1 I have posted. 
`const keytermsSecurityTypes = Object.keys(obj1);`